# How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I change the class of an HTML element in response to an `onclick` or any other events using JavaScript?

Comment: "The class attribute is mostly used to point to a class in a style sheet. However, it can also be used by a JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to make changes to HTML elements with a specified class." -http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_class.asp

Comment: `element.setAttribute(name, value);`  Replace `name` with `class`.  Replace `value` with whatever name you have given the class, enclosed in quotes.  This avoids needing to delete the current class and adding a different one.  This [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/U2PCA/) shows full working code.

Comment: For changing a class of HTML element with onClick use this code:
`<input type='button' onclick='addNewClass(this)' value='Create' />`   and in javascript section: `function addNewClass(elem){
  elem.className="newClass";`
}    [Online](http://jsbin.com/jucuwo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @Triynko - that link on w3schools has changed, looks like in September 2012. Here is that page on Archive.org from 12/Sep/2012: [HTML class Attribute-w3schools](http://web.archive.org/web/20120912065825/http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_class.asp). Here is the link for the replacement page on w3schools.com: [HTML class Attribute-w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp).

Comment: @ImanBahrampour That will obliterate any existing classes.

Answer (score 4623, accepted):

### Modern HTML5 Techniques for changing classes

Modern browsers have added [**classList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) which provides methods to make it easier to manipulate classes without needing a library:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.add('MyClass');

document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('MyClass');

if ( document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.contains('MyClass') )

document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.toggle('MyClass');
```

Unfortunately, these do not work in Internet Explorer prior to v10, though there is a [shim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)) to add support for it to IE8 and IE9, available from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList). It is, though, getting more and more [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist).

### Simple cross-browser solution

The standard JavaScript way to select an element is using [`document.getElementById("Id")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById), which is what the following examples use - you can of course obtain elements in other ways, and in the right situation may simply use `this` instead - however, going into detail on this is beyond the scope of the answer.

#### To change all classes for an element:

To replace all existing classes with one or more new classes, set the className attribute:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

(You can use a space-delimited list to apply multiple classes.)

#### To add an additional class to an element:

To add a class to an element, without removing/affecting existing values, append a space and the new classname, like so:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " MyClass";
```

#### To remove a class from an element:

To remove a single class to an element, without affecting other potential classes, a simple regex replace is required:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className =
   document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace
      ( /(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/g , '' )
/* Code wrapped for readability - above is all one statement */
```

An explanation of this regex is as follows:

```
(?:^|\s) # Match the start of the string or any single whitespace character

MyClass  # The literal text for the classname to remove

(?!\S)   # Negative lookahead to verify the above is the whole classname
         # Ensures there is no non-space character following
         # (i.e. must be the end of the string or space)
```

The `g` flag tells the replace to repeat as required, in case the class name has been added multiple times.

#### To check if a class is already applied to an element:

The same regex used above for removing a class can also be used as a check as to whether a particular class exists:

```
if ( document.getElementById("MyElement").className.match(/(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/) )
```

### Assigning these actions to onClick events:

Whilst it is possible to write JavaScript directly inside the HTML event attributes (such as `onClick="this.className+=' MyClass'"`) this is not recommended behavior. Especially on larger applications, more maintainable code is achieved by separating HTML markup from JavaScript interaction logic.

The first step to achieving this is by creating a function, and calling the function in the onClick attribute, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass(){
        // Code examples from above
    }
</script>
...
<button onClick="changeClass()">My Button</button>
```

<sub>*(It is not required to have this code in script tags, this is simply for the brevity of example, and including the JavaScript in a distinct file may be more appropriate.)*</sub>

The second step is to move the onClick event out of the HTML and into JavaScript, for example using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass(){
        // Code examples from above
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("MyElement").addEventListener( 'click', changeClass);
    }
</script>
...
<button id="MyElement">My Button</button>
```

(Note that the window.onload part is required so that the contents of that function are executed *after* the HTML has finished loading - without this, the MyElement might not exist when the JavaScript code is called, so that line would fail.)

### JavaScript Frameworks and Libraries

The above code is all in standard JavaScript, however, it is common practice to use either a framework or a library to simplify common tasks, as well as benefit from fixed bugs and edge cases that you might not think of when writing your code.

Whilst some people consider it overkill to add a ~50  KB framework for simply changing a class, if you are doing any substantial amount of JavaScript work or anything that might have unusual cross-browser behavior, it is well worth considering.

*(Very roughly, a library is a set of tools designed for a specific task, whilst a framework generally contains multiple libraries and performs a complete set of duties.)*

The examples above have been reproduced below using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), probably the most commonly used JavaScript library (though there are others worth investigating too).

(Note that `$` here is the jQuery object.)

#### Changing Classes with jQuery:

```
$('#MyElement').addClass('MyClass');

$('#MyElement').removeClass('MyClass');

if ( $('#MyElement').hasClass('MyClass') )
```

In addition, jQuery provides a shortcut for adding a class if it doesn't apply, or removing a class that does:

```
$('#MyElement').toggleClass('MyClass');
```

### Assigning a function to a click event with jQuery:

```
$('#MyElement').click(changeClass);
```

or, without needing an id:

```
$(':button:contains(My Button)').click(changeClass);
```

Comment: Great answer Peter. One question... why is it **better** to do with with JQuery than Javascript? JQuery is great, but if this is all you need to do - what justifies including the entire JQuery libray instead of a few lines of JavaScript?

Comment: @mattstuehler 1) the phrase "better yet x" *often* means "better yet (you can) x".  2) To get to the heart of the matter, jQuery is designed to aid in accessing/manipulating the DOM, and very often if you need to do this sort of thing once you have to do it all over the place.

Comment: Be ware of that in case of Add Class Name there MUSt be White Space in front of the Class Name you want to add.

Comment: if you add a class does the previous class get removed, or you have to do that manually?

Comment: Previous classes will stay. You'll have to remove other classes manually if you want to do that.

Comment: One bug with this solution: When you click on your button multiple times, it will add the Class of " MyClass" to the element multiple times, rather than checking to see if it already exists. Thus you could end up with an HTML class attribute looking something like this: `class="button MyClass MyClass MyClass"`

Comment: I guess the solution to that would be: `if ( ! document.getElementById("MyElement").className.match(/(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/) )`
or, with jQuery: `if ( ! $j('#MyElement').hasClass('MyClass') )` (although I suspect addClass wont add duplicates?)

Comment: If you're trying to remove a class 'myClass' and you have a class 'prefix-myClass' the regex you gave above for removing a class will leave you with 'prefix-' in your className :O

Comment: Wow, three years and 183 upvotes and nobody spotted that until now. Thanks jinglesthula, I've corrected the regex so it wont incorrectly remove parts of class names. // I guess this is a good example of why a Framework (like jQuery) is worth using - bugs like this are caught and fixed sooner, and don't require changes to normal code.

Comment: I've done some minor edits to improve the answer - hopefully people agree they are improvements? If there's anything else I've missed let me know (or just edit the answer yourself).

Comment: @PeterBoughton Not sure if you think this is an improvement, but I like: `(' '+document.getElementById("MyElement").className+' ').replace( ' '+MyClass+' ' , '' )`

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. you are collapsing the surrounding spaces and regex to a null, which will concatenate the surrounding class name strings (if any) together. I think elem.className = elem.className.replace( ' ' + classname + ' ' , ' ' ) is what we want. Thanks!

Comment: I use similar methods, but with a g (general) regex. the reason is exactly the issue described by @Web_Designer above: if the user clicks several times, you end up with multiple instances of the same class, and all instances must be removed to remove the class.

Comment: Importing an entire library to accomplish one, simple task is precisely why there is so much overhead drifting around the internet. So I disagree that resorting to JQuery is the "better" solution.

Comment: I have just made substantial additions to this answer - the bulk is the same, but I would appreciate feedback on if there's any mistakes or places for further improvement.

Comment: When creating the regex with a variable for the class name I had to look up the syntax: `var regExp = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + classToAddOrRemove + '(?!\\S)', 'g');`

Comment: One important detail missing here is the difference between framework and library. jQuery is a library, not a framework. Just for the safe of the example, a framework would be angularJs, for example.

Comment: _(You can specify a space-delimited list of elements.)_
You must mean a list of classes to assign, not elements to select.

Comment: Really excellent answer that fails completely to answer the OP's question: how do you *change* the value of an existing class?

Comment: If it doesn't answer the OP's question, why did they mark it as the solution? _Your question_ appears to be a different one (possibly you want to change the CSS properties/declarations linked to a class name? not sure if browsers allow that) - why not clarify what you're after in a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which explains precisely what you want / are trying to achieve?

Comment: With regards to the "To add an additional class to an element" point (2nd in list), I find it's best to grab the current `el.className`, string concat with `" class-to-add"`, and finally call a `.trim()` on the string before updating the target element. That said, I don't think CSS really cares about the `\s`, an element's individual classes are determined by a space-separated list anyway.

Comment: heh: `var a=[];e.className=((a=e.className.split(" ")).splice(a.indexOf(oldClass),1,newClass)&&a).join(" ").trim();`  :D

Comment: Can you please rearrange things? **In my opinion** the classList with shim for browser support should be at the top.

Comment: would b cool if smth like this worked too, to remove a class name: `document.getElementById("MyElement").className -= " MyClass";`

Comment: so the answer simply is $('#MyElement').toggleClass('MyClass');

thanks, It works for me

Comment: \b matches next to hyphens.

Comment: There are faster methods than removing class using RegExp, especially if you're going to turn it into a polyfill. See http://jsperf.com/removeclass-methods

Comment: Your method for removing a class *almost* takes care of removing extra spaces that may appear after removing items. But it can happen that the result will start with a leading space. If you add a .trim(), your method for removing a class will not contain any extra spaces.

Comment: Also, you can safely remove the "?:" in the beginning of the RegEx, such that it reads: new RegExp​("​(\\s|^​)"+className+"​(?!\\S​)","g"​)

Comment: Excellent answer, too bad you left out an example for "(You can use a space-delimited list to apply multiple classes.)" because that would have saved so much time.

Comment: [Difference between ClassList and ClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69361464/1705829)

Comment: You can also assign directly to the `classList` property: `element.classList = "classA classB";`. This works because the [Element Web IDL definition](//dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element) defines the `classList` property with the [\[PutForwards=`value`\] extended attribute](//webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#PutForwards) which allows this assignment to invoke the [`element.classList.value` setter](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/value) instead. And this setter accepts a white space separated string.

Answer (score 488):

You could also just do:

```js
document.getElementById('id').classList.add('class');
document.getElementById('id').classList.remove('class');
```

And to toggle a class (remove if exists else add it):

```js
document.getElementById('id').classList.toggle('class');
```

Comment: I believe this is HTML5 dependent.

Comment: You’ll need Eli Grey’s `classList` shim.

Comment: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) states that it doesn't work, natively, in Internet Explorers less than 10.  I find the statement to be true, in my testing.  Apparently, the [Eli Grey shim](http://eligrey.com) is required for Internet Explorer 8-9.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find it on his site (even with searching).  The shim is available on the Mozilla link.

Comment: Feature not supported until a few hours ago (added on IE10 and Android 3)

Comment: [Here's the MDN Documentation for `classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: atow "classList" has partial support in IE10+; no support for Opera Mini; else full support in remaining standard browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist

Comment: I think the Eli Grey shim can be found [here](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/)...

Answer (score 147):

In one of my old projects that did not use jQuery, I built the following functions for adding, removing and checking if an element has a class:

```
function hasClass(ele, cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(ele, cls) {
    if (!hasClass(ele, cls))
        ele.className += " " + cls;
}

function removeClass(ele, cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele, cls)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)');
        ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg, ' ');
    }
}
```

So, for example, if I want `onclick` to add some class to the button I can use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass(btn, cls) {
        if(!hasClass(btn, cls)) {
            addClass(btn, cls);
        }
    }
</script>
...
<button onclick="changeClass(this, "someClass")">My Button</button>
```

By now for sure it would just be better to use jQuery.

Comment: This is great for when your client doesn't let you use jQuery. (Cause you end up almost building your own library.)

Comment: @Mike If the client doesn't let you use jQuery, could you not just go through and rebuild only the features you needed into your own library?

Comment: @kfrncs Because I don't generally need that large of a framework. For the project I was thinking of, the only functions I needed were the 3 classname(has,add,remove) functions and the cookie(has, add, remove) functions. Everything else was either custom, or natively well supported. So everything together was then only 150 lines before minifying, including comments.

Comment: This is my favorite solution for this. I use it everywhere. I believe it is the most elegant way to achieve adding and removing classes when your project does not already have another way of doing it.

Comment: It should be noted that after using `addClass` and `removeClass` on the same element, the element's className will contain an additional space. The className modifying line of `removeClass` should be updated to `ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg, ' ').trim().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');`. This removes trailing whitespace left over and collapses multiple whitespaces into a single space in the className.

Comment: @WebWanderer So this is just my opinion, don't call me rude, but I hate doing string acrobatics. I try to never use regexes. This is not elegant at all. Tyilo's answer is elegant. I do think class hopping is mostly used for fancy stuff. And if the resources we are dealing with here are important, don't use too much fancy stuff. And if your browser doesn't support these things, let the user suck on it and update their browser.

Comment: @Bitterblue my comment and suggestion are 4.5 years old, back when I cared about browsers that didn't support Tyilo's answer. I've been actively doing web app development throughout those years, and haven't needed to do class swapping like this in years.

Answer (score 106):

You can use `node.className` like so:

```
document.getElementById('foo').className = 'bar';
```

This should work in [Internet Explorer 5.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_5#Versions) and up according to [PPK](http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html).

Comment: this would overwrite any and all other classes on the object... so it is not that simple.

Answer (score 62):

Using pure JavaScript code:

```
function hasClass(ele, cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(ele, cls) {
    if (!this.hasClass(ele, cls)) ele.className += " " + cls;
}

function removeClass(ele, cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele, cls)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)');
        ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg, ' ');
    }
}

function replaceClass(ele, oldClass, newClass){
    if(hasClass(ele, oldClass)){
        removeClass(ele, oldClass);
        addClass(ele, newClass);
    }
    return;
}

function toggleClass(ele, cls1, cls2){
    if(hasClass(ele, cls1)){
        replaceClass(ele, cls1, cls2);
    }else if(hasClass(ele, cls2)){
        replaceClass(ele, cls2, cls1);
    }else{
        addClass(ele, cls1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 61):

Wow, surprised there are so many overkill answers here...

```
<div class="firstClass" onclick="this.className='secondClass'">
```

Comment: I would say unobtrusive javascript is terrible practice for writing example code...

Comment: I would disagree, because I think example code should set a good example.

Comment: A good example  should instruct and spark the imagination at the same time. It should not replace thought, but inspire it.

Comment: The other answers aren't overkill, they also keep existing classes on the element.

Answer (score 46):

## 4 actions possible: Add, Remove, Check, and Toggle

Let's see multiple ways for each action.

### 1. Add class

**Method 1:** Best way to add a class in the modern browser is using `classList.add()` method of element.

- **Case 1**: Adding single class

  ```js
  function addClass() {
    let element = document.getElementById('id1');

    // adding class
    element.classList.add('beautify');
  }
  ```
- **Case 2**: Adding multiple class

  To add multiple classes saperate classes by a comma in the `add()` method

  ```js
  function addClass() {
    let element = document.getElementById('id1');

    // adding multiple class
    element.classList.add('class1', 'class2', 'class3');
  }
  ```

**Method 2** - You can also add classes to HTML elements using `className` property.

- **Case 1**: Overwriting pre-existing classes
  When you assign a new class to the `className` property it overwrites the previous class.

  ```js
  function addClass() {
    let element = document.getElementById('id1');

    // adding multiple class
    element.className = 'beautify';
  }
  ```
- **Case 2**: Adding class without overwrite
  Use `+=` operator for class not to overwrite previous classes. Also, add an extra space before the new class.

  ```js
  function addClass() {
    let element = document.getElementById('id1');

    // adding single multiple class
    element.className += ' beautify';
    // adding multiple classes
    element.className += ' class1 class2 class3';
  }
  ```

---

### 2. Remove class

**Method 1** - The best way to remove a class from an element is the `classList.remove()` method.

- **Case 1**: Remove single class

  Just pass the class name you want to remove from the element in the method.

  ```js
  function removeClass() {
    let element = document.getElementById('id1');

    // removing class
    element.classList.remove('beautify');
  }
  ```
- **Case 2**: Remove multiple class

  Pass multiple classes separated by a comma.

  ```js
  function removeClass() {
    let element = document.getElementById('id1');

    // removing class
    element.classList.remove('class1', 'class2', 'class3');
  }
  ```

**Method 2** - You can also remove class using `className` method.

- **Case 1**: Removing single class
  If the element has only 1 class and you want to remove it then just assign an empty string to the `className` method.

  ```js
  function removeClass() {
    let element = document.getElementById('id1');

    // removing class
    element.className = '';
  }
  ```
- **Case 2**: Removing multiple class
  If the element has multiple classes first get all classes from the element using the `className` property and use replace method and replace desired classes with an empty string and finally assign it to element's `className` property.

  ```js
  function removeClass() {
    let element = document.getElementById('id1');

    // removing class
    element.className = element.className.replace('class1', '');
  }
  ```

---

### 3. Checking class

To check if a class exists in the element you can simply use **`classList.contains()`** method. It returns `true` if the class exists else returns false.

```
function checkClass() {
  let element = document.getElementById('id1');

  // checking class
  if(element.classList.contains('beautify') {
      alert('Yes! class exists');
  }
}
```

---

### 4. Toggle class

To toggle a class use **`classList.toggle()`** method.

```js
function toggleClass() {
    let element = document.getElementById('id1');

    // toggle class
    element.classList.toggle('beautify');
}
```

Answer (score 43):

This is working for me:

```
function setCSS(eleID) {
    var currTabElem = document.getElementById(eleID);

    currTabElem.setAttribute("class", "some_class_name");
    currTabElem.setAttribute("className", "some_class_name");
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Just left to add : Set for each CSS class name for selector to specify a style for a group of class elements

Comment: This works for me on FF, but when I've tried to use el.className = "newStyle"; it didn't worked, why?

Comment: You can use `el.setAttribute('class', newClass)` or better `el.className = newClass`. But not `el.setAttribute('className', newClass)`.

Answer (score 29):

As well you could extend HTMLElement object, in order to add methods to add, remove, toggle and check classes ([gist](https://gist.github.com/Maksims/5356227)):

```
HTMLElement = typeof(HTMLElement) != 'undefiend' ? HTMLElement : Element;

HTMLElement.prototype.addClass = function(string) {
  if (!(string instanceof Array)) {
    string = string.split(' ');
  }
  for(var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (string[i] && !new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string[i] + '(\\s+|$)').test(this.className)) {
      this.className = this.className.trim() + ' ' + string[i];
    }
  }
}

HTMLElement.prototype.removeClass = function(string) {
  if (!(string instanceof Array)) {
    string = string.split(' ');
  }
  for(var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; ++i) {
    this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string[i] + '(\\s+|$)'), ' ').trim();
  }
}

HTMLElement.prototype.toggleClass = function(string) {
  if (string) {
    if (new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string + '(\\s+|$)').test(this.className)) {
      this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string + '(\\s+|$)'), ' ').trim();
    } else {
      this.className = this.className.trim() + ' ' + string;
    }
  }
}

HTMLElement.prototype.hasClass = function(string) {
  return string && new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string + '(\\s+|$)').test(this.className);
}
```

And then just use like this (on click will add or remove class):

```
document.getElementById('yourElementId').onclick = function() {
  this.toggleClass('active');
}
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5QMgR/).

Answer (score 26):

Just to add on information from another popular framework, Google Closures, see their [dom/classes](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_dom_classes.js.html) class:

```
goog.dom.classes.add(element, var_args)

goog.dom.classes.addRemove(element, classesToRemove, classesToAdd)

goog.dom.classes.remove(element, var_args)
```

One option for selecting the element is using [goog.dom.query](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_third_party_closure_goog_dojo_dom_query.js.html) with a CSS 3 selector:

```
var myElement = goog.dom.query("#MyElement")[0];
```

Answer (score 22):

Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript in [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        lbSave.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className = 'LinkButtonStyle1'")
        lbSave.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className = 'LinkButtonStyle'")
        lbCancel.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className = 'LinkButtonStyle1'")
        lbCancel.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className = 'LinkButtonStyle'")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 22):

A couple of minor notes and tweaks on the previous regexes:

You'll want to do it globally in case the class list has the class name more than once. And, you'll probably want to strip spaces from the ends of the class list and convert multiple spaces to one space to keep from getting runs of spaces. None of these things should be a problem if the only code dinking with the class names uses the regex below and removes a name before adding it. But. Well, who knows who might be dinking with the class name list.

This regex is case insensitive so that bugs in class names may show up before the code is used on a browser that doesn't care about case in class names.

```
var s = "testing   one   four  one  two";
var cls = "one";
var rg          = new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + cls + "(\\s+|$)", 'ig');
alert("[" + s.replace(rg, ' ') + "]");
var cls = "test";
var rg          = new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + cls + "(\\s+|$)", 'ig');
alert("[" + s.replace(rg, ' ') + "]");
var cls = "testing";
var rg          = new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + cls + "(\\s+|$)", 'ig');
alert("[" + s.replace(rg, ' ') + "]");
var cls = "tWo";
var rg          = new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + cls + "(\\s+|$)", 'ig');
alert("[" + s.replace(rg, ' ') + "]");
```

Answer (score 19):

The line

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace(/\bMyClass\b/','')
```

should be:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace('/\bMyClass\b/','');
```

Comment: Incorrect. The RegEx is delimeted by the forward slashes. Adding quotes causes it to fail in IE, returning the string of the class you're trying to remove rather than actually removing the class.

Answer (score 19):

I would use jQuery and write something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#some-element").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    });
});
```

This code adds a function to be called when an element of the id **some-element** is clicked. The function appends **clicked** to the element's class attribute if it's not already part of it, and removes it if it's there.

Yes, you do need to add a reference to the jQuery library in your page to use this code, but at least you can feel confident the most functions in the library would work on pretty much all the modern browsers, and it will save you time implementing your own code to do the same.

Comment: You only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once. `jQuery(function($) { });` makes `$` available inside the function in all cases.

Answer (score 17):

## Change an element's class in vanilla JavaScript with Internet Explorer 6 support

You may try to use the node `attributes` property to keep compatibility with old browsers, even Internet Explorer 6:

```js
function getClassNode(element) {
  for (var i = element.attributes.length; i--;)
    if (element.attributes[i].nodeName === 'class')
      return element.attributes[i];
}

function removeClass(classNode, className) {
  var index, classList = classNode.value.split(' ');
  if ((index = classList.indexOf(className)) > -1) {
    classList.splice(index, 1);
    classNode.value = classList.join(' ');
  }
}

function hasClass(classNode, className) {
  return classNode.value.indexOf(className) > -1;
}

function addClass(classNode, className) {
  if (!hasClass(classNode, className))
    classNode.value += ' ' + className;
}

document.getElementById('message').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var classNode = getClassNode(this);
  var className = hasClass(classNode, 'red') && 'blue' || 'red';

  removeClass(classNode, 'red');
  removeClass(classNode, 'blue');

  addClass(classNode, className);
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.red:before {
  content: 'I am red! ';
}
.red:after {
  content: ' again';
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.blue:before {
  content: 'I am blue! '
}
```

```html
<span id="message" class="">Click me</span>
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's my version, fully working:

```
function addHTMLClass(item, classname) {
    var obj = item
    if (typeof item=="string") {
        obj = document.getElementById(item)
    }
    obj.className += " " + classname
}

function removeHTMLClass(item, classname) {
    var obj = item
    if (typeof item=="string") {
        obj = document.getElementById(item)
    }
    var classes = ""+obj.className
    while (classes.indexOf(classname)>-1) {
        classes = classes.replace (classname, "")
    }
    obj.className = classes
}
```

Usage:

```
<tr onmouseover='addHTMLClass(this,"clsSelected")'
onmouseout='removeHTMLClass(this,"clsSelected")' >
```

Comment: That will break class `foobar` if you try to remove class `foo`. The JS in the intrinsic event handler attributes was broken before being edited. The 4 year old accepted answer is much better.

Comment: thanks, i fixed it (not the prefix problem). it's the old accepted answer that have a bug with the regexp.

Comment: The code still have the `foobar` problem. See the test [here](http://picoquery.com/lab/youmightnotneedjquery-tests/removeclass/)

Answer (score 13):

Here's a toggleClass to toggle/add/remove a class on an element:

```
// If newState is provided add/remove theClass accordingly, otherwise toggle theClass
function toggleClass(elem, theClass, newState) {
    var matchRegExp = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + theClass + '(?!\\S)', 'g');
    var add=(arguments.length>2 ? newState : (elem.className.match(matchRegExp) == null));

    elem.className=elem.className.replace(matchRegExp, ''); // clear all
    if (add) elem.className += ' ' + theClass;
}
```

See [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLuhp9se/).

Also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42941303/460084) for creating a new class dynamically.

Answer (score 11):

I use the following vanilla JavaScript functions in my code. They use regular expressions and `indexOf` but do not require quoting special characters in regular expressions.

```
function addClass(el, cn) {
    var c0 = (" " + el.className + " ").replace(/\s+/g, " "),
        c1 = (" " + cn + " ").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
    if (c0.indexOf(c1) < 0) {
        el.className = (c0 + c1).replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/^ | $/g, "");
    }
}

function delClass(el, cn) {
    var c0 = (" " + el.className + " ").replace(/\s+/g, " "),
        c1 = (" " + cn + " ").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
    if (c0.indexOf(c1) >= 0) {
        el.className = c0.replace(c1, " ").replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/^ | $/g, "");
    }
}
```

You can also use [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) in modern browsers.

Answer (score 8):

The OP question was *How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?*

Modern browsers allow you to do this **with one line of JavaScript**:

`document.getElementById('id').classList.replace('span1', 'span2')`

The `classList` attribute provides a DOMTokenList which has a [variety of methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList). You can operate on an element's classList using simple manipulations like *add()*, *remove()* or *replace()*. Or get very sophisticated and manipulate classes like you would an object or Map with *keys()*, *values()*, and *entries()*.

[Peter Boughton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript/196038#196038) is a great one, but it's now over a decade old. All modern browsers now support DOMTokenList - see https://caniuse.com/#search=classList and even [Internet Explorer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11) supports some DOMTokenList methods.

Answer (score 7):

---

## THE OPTIONS.

Here is a little style vs. classList examples to get you to see what are the options you have available and how to use `classList` to do what you want.

## [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) vs. [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

The difference between `style` and `classList` is that with `style` you're adding to the style properties of the element, but `classList` is kinda controlling the class(es) of the element (`add`, `remove`, `toggle`, `contain`), I will show you how to use the `add` and `remove` method since those are the popular ones.

---

### Style Example

If you want to add `margin-top`  property into an element, you would do in such:

```
// Get the Element
const el = document.querySelector('#element');

// Add CSS property 
el.style.margintop = "0px"
el.style.margintop = "25px" // This would add a 25px to the top of the element.
```

---

### classList Example

Let say we have a `<div class="class-a class-b">`, in this case, we have 2 classes added to our div element already, `class-a` and `class-b`, and we want to control what classes **`remove`** and what class to **`add`**. This is where `classList` becomes handy.

#### Remove `class-b`

```
// Get the Element
const el = document.querySelector('#element');

// Remove class-b style from the element
el.classList.remove("class-b")
```

#### Add `class-c`

```
// Get the Element
const el = document.querySelector('#element');

// Add class-b style from the element
el.classList.add("class-c")
```

---

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
element.className='second'
```

```js
function change(box) { box.className='second' }
```

```css
.first  { width:  70px; height:  70px; background: #ff0                 }
.second { width: 150px; height: 150px; background: #f00; transition: 1s }
```

```html
<div onclick="change(this)" class="first">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

For IE v6-9 (in which `classList` is not supported and you don't want to use polyfills):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('some-id');

// don't forget the extra space before the class name
var classList = elem.getAttribute('class') + ' other-class-name';

elem.setAttribute('class', classList);
```

Answer (score 5):

OK, I think in this case you should use jQuery or write your own Methods in pure JavaScript. My preference is adding my own methods rather than injecting all jQuery to my application if I don't need that for other reasons.

I'd like to do something like below as methods to my JavaScript framework to add few functionalities which handle adding classes, deleting classes, etc. Similar to jQuery, this is fully supported in IE9+. Also my code is written in ES6, so you need to make sure your browser support it or you using something like [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)), otherwise need to use ES5 syntax in your code. Also in this way, we finding element via ID, which means the element needs to have an ID to be selected:

```
// Simple JavaScript utilities for class management in ES6
var classUtil = {

  addClass: (id, cl) => {
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add(cl);
  },

  removeClass: (id, cl) => {
    document.getElementById(id).classList.remove(cl);
  },

  hasClass: (id, cl) => {
    return document.getElementById(id).classList.contains(cl);
  },

  toggleClass: (id, cl) => {
    document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle(cl);
  }

}
```

And you can simply use them as below. Imagine your element has id of 'id' and class of 'class'. Make sure you pass them as a string. You can use the utility as below:

```
classUtil.addClass('myId', 'myClass');
classUtil.removeClass('myId', 'myClass');
classUtil.hasClass('myId', 'myClass');
classUtil.toggleClass('myId', 'myClass');
```

Answer (score 4):

### `classList` DOM API:

A very convenient manner of adding and removing classes is the `classList` DOM API. This API allows us to select all classes of a specific DOM element in order to modify the list using JavaScript. For example:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("main");
console.log(el.classList);
```

```html
<div class="content wrapper animated" id="main"></div>
```

We can observe in the log that we are getting back an object with not only the classes of the element, but also many auxiliary methods and properties. This object inherits from the interface **DOMTokenList**, an interface which is used in the DOM to represent a set of space separated tokens (like classes).

### Example:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('container');

function addClass () {
    el.classList.add('newclass');
}


function replaceClass () {
    el.classList.replace('foo', 'newFoo');
}


function removeClass () {
    el.classList.remove('bar');
}
```

```css
button{
  margin: 20px;
}

.foo{
  color: red;
}

.newFoo {
  color: blue;
}

.bar{
  background-color: powderblue;
}

.newclass{
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo bar" id="container">
  "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis
  iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
  totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et
  quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam
  voluptatem quia voluptas
 </div>

<button onclick="addClass()">AddClass</button>

<button onclick="replaceClass()">ReplaceClass</button>

<button onclick="removeClass()">removeClass</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are many ways to do this. In ES6 syntax we can achieve easily. Use this code toggle add and remove class.

```js
const tabs=document.querySelectorAll('.menu li');

for(let tab of tabs){

  tab.onclick = function(){

    let activetab = document.querySelectorAll('li.active');

    activetab[0].classList.remove('active')

    tab.classList.add('active');
  }

}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
    margin: 20px 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    background: #dfdfdf;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.active {
    background: #2794c7;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<i>Please click an item:</i>

<ul class="menu">
  <li class="active"><span>Three</span></li>
  <li><span>Two</span></li>
  <li><span>One</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Use this code toggle add and remove class."*? It seems incomprehensible. E.g., is some punctuation missing? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54555429/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I'd throw this in:

```
function inArray(val, ary){
  for(var i=0,l=ary.length; i<l; i++){
    if(ary[i] === val){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
function removeClassName(classNameS, fromElement){
  var x = classNameS.split(/\s/), s = fromElement.className.split(/\s/), r = [];
  for(var i=0,l=s.length; i<l; i++){
    if(!iA(s[i], x))r.push(s[i]);
  }
  fromElement.className = r.join(' ');
}
function addClassName(classNameS, toElement){
  var s = toElement.className.split(/\s/);
  s.push(c); toElement.className = s.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `myElement.classList="new-class"` unless you need to maintain other existing classes in which case you can use the `classList.add, .remove` methods.

```js
var doc = document;
var divOne = doc.getElementById("one");
var goButton = doc.getElementById("go");

goButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  divOne.classList="blue";
});
```

```css
div{
  min-height: 48px;
  min-width: 48px;
}
.bordered{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button id="go">Change Class</button>

<div id="one" class="bordered green">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

```
document.getElementById('id').className = 'class'
```

*OR*

```
document.getElementById('id').classList.add('class');
document.getElementById('id').classList.remove('class');
```

***That's it.***

And, if you really want to know the why and educate yourself then I suggest reading [Peter Boughton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/1804013). It's perfect.

**Note:**

This is possible with (*[document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)* or *[event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)*):

- `getElementById()`
- `getElementsByClassName()`
- `querySelector()`
- `querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 2):

```
function classed(el, class_name, add_class) {
  const re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + class_name + "(?!\\S)", "g");
  if (add_class && !el.className.match(re)) el.className += " " + class_name
  else if (!add_class) el.className = el.className.replace(re, '');
}
```

Using [Peter Boughton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript/196038#196038), here is a simple cross-browser function to add and remove class.

Add class:

```
classed(document.getElementById("denis"), "active", true)
```

Remove class:

```
classed(document.getElementById("denis"), "active", false)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a property, **className**, in JavaScript to change the name of the class of an HTML element. The existing class value will be replaced with the new one, that you have assigned in className.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>How can I change the class of an HTML element in JavaScript?</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center"><i class="fa fa-home" id="icon"></i></h1><br />

<center><button id="change-class">Change Class</button></center>

<script>
var change_class = document.getElementById("change-class");
change_class.onclick = function()
{
    var icon=document.getElementById("icon");
    icon.className = "fa fa-gear";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Credit - *[How To Change Class Name of an HTML Element in JavaScript](https://jaischool.com/javascript-lang/how-to-change-class-name-of-an-html-element-in-javascript.html)*

Answer (score 1):

To change the class you can use following functiionalities:

HTML:

```
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>
```

Javascript:

```
const button = document.getElementById('myButton');

button.onclick = function() {
  button.classList.add('newClass');
};
```

CSS:

```
.newClass {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score -6):

Here is a simple jQuery code to do that:

```
$(".class1").click(function(argument) {
    $(".parentclass").removeClass("classtoremove");
    setTimeout(function (argument) {
        $(".parentclass").addClass("classtoadd");
    }, 100);
});
```

Here,

- Class1 is a listener for an event.
- The parent class is the class which hosts the class you want to change
- Classtoremove is the old class you have.
- Class to add is the new class that you want to add.
- 100 is the timeout delay during which the class is changed.

Answer (score -30):

This is easiest with a library like jQuery:

```
<input type="button" onClick="javascript:test_byid();" value="id='second'" />

<script>
function test_byid()
{
    $("#second").toggleClass("highlight");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does the javascript: pseudo-protocol do in a script-event ...  It seems totally stupid to tell the javascript-interpretator, that it should treat script in a script-event as script !-)  Only use of the javascript: pseudo-protocol is where you instead would use an url !o]

Comment: In that context, it isn't the pseudo-protocol - it's a loop label ... only there is no loop for it TO label.

Comment: Actually, that is not a pseudo-protocol, it is interpreted as a JavaScript label, like what you can use in a loop. One could easily do `onClick="myScriptYo:do_it();"`. But, please, don't do it.

Answer (score -73):

No offense, but it's unclever to change class on-the-fly as it forces the CSS interpreter to recalculate the visual presentation of the entire web page.

The reason is that it is nearly impossible for the CSS interpreter to know if any inheritance or cascading could be changed, so the short answer is:

Never ever change className on-the-fly !-)

But usually you'll only need to change a property or two, and that is easily implemented:

```
function highlight(elm){
    elm.style.backgroundColor ="#345";
    elm.style.color = "#fff";
}
```

Comment: i've never experienced any performance issues with switching CSS classes myself. I think whatever performance hit there *might* be, it's far outweighed by the messiness of having styles/presentation mixed up in your javascript.

Comment: Hrm, obviously you never tested it ... In a realtime application consisting of thousands of rows nested with other elements I recognized a delay of several seconds, remaking it only to change properties it wasn't possible to recognize delay ...

Comment: Why would you even want thousands of rows nested with other elements?

Also, what operating system & browser was this delay with?

Comment: If changing a className is causing noticeable performance problems, you have much bigger problems in the structure and design of your page/app. If not, shaving off a few milliseconds is not a good reason to pollute your application logic with styles.

Comment: this is the worst idea ever. changing classes is by far and away the easiest and cleanest way to update your CSS on the fly.

Comment: To the “thousands of rows” unbelievers: doxygen. Hierarchical, collapsible menus in a side frame. IE7 had fatal issues with this so I used Firefox.

Comment: I'm wondering why you haven't deleted your answer yet! *(it's 2016)*

Comment: @AlexJolig - the user hasn't logged in since 2009

Comment: This is the second-most downvoted answer on the site.

Comment: I think "don't do it in the first place" is not an acceptable answer for "how to do it".

Comment: So instead of changing a class you go with writing inline styles by hand. You are taking CSS's job. By the way, if you edit the style attribute, it will also redraw the page as it would if you would have changed the class. _"obviously you never tested it"_ - show us some exact data on how your solution is faster. And please don't give us data like "It's 40% faster, when you execute 20 million changes" or something like that.